# unable to remove autocomplete suggestions in asp .net login control

Tags: c#, .net

I have an ASP .Net login control on login form and want to disable autocomplete in username textbox. I tried googling for few days but none of the suggestions have worked till now.

I put up control outside asp:login control and was able to disable autocomplete but username inside asp:login control always suggest autocomplete text. Here is the link of aspx code for your review - https://googleapp.startsso.com/login.txt

Comment: have you tried with <input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>

Comment: yes tried almost all sols available on net but not working so thought to attach my code as a link above.

Comment: check if there is any javascript  ?

Comment: sorry my fault. its coming from cookie and not due to autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

add `autocomplete` attribute to your form tag, like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```